# Java Stream stateful findFirst

Tags: java, java-stream

The below method is part of a weighted random selection algorithm for picking songs.

I would like to convert the below method to use streams, to decide if it would be clearer / preferable. I am not certain it is possible at all, since calculation is a stateful operation, dependent on position in the list.

```
public Song songForTicketNumber(long ticket)
{
    if(ticket<0) return null;
    long remaining = ticket;
    for(Song s : allSongs)  // allSongs is ordered list
    {
        rem-=s.numTickets; // numTickets is a long and never negative
        if(remaining<0)
            return s;
    }
    return null;
}
```

More formally: If `n` is the sum of all `Song::numTickets` for each `Song` object in `allSongs`, then for any integer `0` through `n-1`, the above method should return a song in the list. The number of integers which will return a specific `Song` object `x`, would be determined by `x.numTickets`. The selection criteria for a specific song is a range of consecutive integers determined by **both** its `numTickets` property and the `numTickets` property for each item in the list to its left. As currently written, anything outside the range would return null.

Note: Out of range behavior can be modified to accommodate Streams (other than returning null)

Comment: This is not suitable for streams.

Comment: Your code is short-circuiting, i.e. stops the loop when the ticket is found. A stream solution would not do that, so don't use stream. Stream is a powerful tool, but like all tools, it only works for certain tasks. Your task is not one of them, and your first hint for that is the word *stateful*. Other than collectors, stream are mostly stateless. It's part of the contract you nee to follow when using stream.

Comment: Streams aren't meant to be stateful. It's also recommended that the function used as the argument of a stream operation should be stateless: "*To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters in most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any state that might change during execution of the stream pipeline).*" - Use streams when it makes things easier (which implies not forcing them, especially if you don't fully understand them). Save time by not focusing on needless changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency of a `Stream` compared to a basic for or for-each loop is a matter of circumstance. In yours, it's highly likely that a `Stream` would be *less* efficient than your current code for, among others, these major reasons:

1. Your function is **stateful** as you mentioned. Maintaining a state with this method probably means finagling some kind of anonymous implementation of a `BinaryOperator` to use with `Stream.reduce`, and it's going to turn out bulkier and more confusing to read than your current code.
2. You're **short circuiting** in your current loop, and no `Stream` operation will reflect that kind of efficiency, especially considering this in combination with #1.
3. Your collection is **ordered**, which means the stream will iterate over elements in a manner very similar to your existing loop anyway. Depending on the size of your collection, you *might* get some efficiency out of `parallelStream`, but having to maintain the order in this case will mean a less efficient stream.

The only real benefit you could get from switching to a `Stream` is the difference in memory consumption (You could keep `allSongs` out of memory and let `Stream` handle it in a more memory-efficient way), which doesn't seem applicable here.

In conclusion, since the `Stream` operations would be even more complex to write and would probably be harmful, if anything, to your efficiency, I would recommend that you do not pursue this change.

That being said, I personally can't come up with a `Stream` based solution to actually answer your question of how to convert this work to a `Stream`. Again, it would be something complex and strange involving a reducer or similar... (I'll delete this answer if this is insufficient.)

Answer (score 0):

Java streams **do** have the facility to short circuit evaluation, see for example the documentation for [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--). Having said that, decrementing and checking `remaining`, requires state mutation which is not great. Not great, but doable:

```java
    public Optional<Song> songForTicketNumber(long ticket, Stream<Song> songs) {
        if (ticket < 0) return Optional.empty();

        AtomicLong remaining = new AtomicLong(ticket);
        return songs.filter(song -> decrementAndCheck(song, remaining)).findFirst();
    }

    private boolean decrementAndCheck(Song song, AtomicLong total) {
        total.addAndGet(-song.numTickets);
        return total.get() < 0;
    }
```

As far as I can tell, the only advantage of this approach is that you could switch to parallel streams if you wanted to.